# Help with caching on codeigniter 2

Tags: php, caching, codeigniter

Code and error output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0W3m.png

“An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested driver: CI_Cache_apc”

Reference:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html

Notes:
Using CI 2.0.2
app/cache and system/libraries/Cache are recursively (files and folders) CHMOD’d 777. The lib one was just for testing if that fixed the problem, it did not.

Thanks!

Comment: Fixed, solution in the comments: https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/issue/193/ci_cache_file

Comment: great. too bad this file has since been deleted. why not post a 'solution' where it belongs? on the page where the question is!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was using CodeIgniter V 2.0.2 and had the same exception for few days. I just updated my framework to [CodeIgniter V 2.0.3](http://codeigniter.com/downloads/). It is working good with APC.

Visit my friends blog testing hosted on my VPS. [Here is Blog Link](http://www.dhavalpatels.com/blog). Also, Take a look at the cache entries on his Virtual Host at http://www.dhavalpatels.com/apc.php

Here is the code

```
<?php

class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    function Blog() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['title'] = "My Blog | DhavalPatels.com";
        $data['head'] = "My ToDo";
        $data['todo'] = array('Go to BestBuy', 'Dinner', 'Call mom');

        $this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file'));

        if ( ! $foo = $this->cache->get('foo')) {
                echo 'Saving to the cache!<br />';
                $foo = 'foobarbaz!';

                // Save into the cache for 5 minutes
                $this->cache->save('foo', $foo, 300);
        }

        echo $foo;

        $this->load->view('blog_view', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your CI is old then replace `system/libraries/drivers.php` from latest CodeIgniter bundle

If your CI is old then replace `system/Cache/` folder from latest CodeIgniter bundle

Add cache path in `config.php`

then run the

```
$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file'));

    if ( ! $foo = $this->cache->get('foo')) {
            echo 'Saving to the cache!<br />';
            $foo = 'foobarbaz!';

            // Save into the cache for 5 minutes
            $this->cache->save('foo', $foo, 300);
    }

    echo $foo;
```

Now my caching is working

Answer (score 0):

despite the doc, try using

```
'adapter' => 'cache_apc'
```

in place of

```
'adapter' => 'apc'
```

Can you check if apc is supported using is_supported($driver)?